# SVN Pre-Commit: Getting name of url when the commit goes

Tags: svn

I need to catch the URL where my files was commited.

**Example:**

My branch is a checkout from http://localhost.home.network:443/svn/test

In my branch was commited the files a.txt and b.txt.

I want to catch using a svn hook (Either pre-commit or post-commit) the URL from my svn respository.

If the question was not clear, ask to me and I'll provide the information needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `svnlook changed` in the post commit hook to get the list of changed files. The output contains the relative paths within the repository, and the root of the repository is passed as first argument to the post commit hook.

You can use the following bash script as `post-commit` hook to see how it works:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
exec >> /tmp/post-commit.log 2>&1
echo "COMMIT: $0 $*"
svnlook changed "$1"
```

Comment: It didn't works. I tried to use the svnlook changed command and I get as answer only the file that was lastly changed. What I really need is to get all the url where the code was commited.

Comment: As I said, the output contain the relative paths, and the parameter `$1` contains the absolute path to the repository. If you know the root URL, you can easily build the URLs for all changed files.

Comment: YES! I figured it out. I got confused because the last commit was on root of my repository and it didn't returned any path, only the name of file. Of course was because of it. Thanks!